# Can org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean be configured to cache WSDLs?

Tags: wsdl, jboss7.x, soap-client, jboss-weld

I am using JBoss 7.1.1 but everytime my EAR makes a SOAP request, it takes about 2 minutes while JBoss creates each service required:

```
14:30:14,822 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-3) Creating Service {http://services.discretewireless.com/v2009_1/}AuthenticationManagerV1Port from WSDL: http://services.discretewireless.com/v2009_1/AuthenticationManagerV1.wsdl
```

Instead of creating the services at runtime, once each time they are used, can I configure something somewhere so that it doesn't have to download the WSDLs and ...Creating Service...from WSDL:... each time one of my beans makes a SOAP request?

Answer (score -1):

You can download the wsdl before running your client and make it available in two different ways: First, CXF's wsdl2java generator lets you fix the location of the wsdl (wsdlLocation) on your classpath, and the wsdl can even be archived in the same jar as your stubs.  Or, second, you can instead pass an url (referencing the local file) to the service's constructor, where the url is something like 'file://path...'

Comment: The question is asked about how to avoid creating client at runtime, the solution you provided is just to avoid downloading the WSDL file.